# Windows XP suddenly in reboot cycle

Tags: windows-xp, boot, windows-update, reboot, safe-mode

A friend called me up today.  Everything was normal yesterday, she browsed with Firefox only and didn't go to any unusual sites.  Shut down normally last night.  This morning whenever she boots she gets a menu where she can choose Normal or Safe Mode, etc., but no matter which one she chooses, she gets the XP logo for a moment, then a blank screen a moment, then the hp logo for a moment, and then her computer reboots itself.

Could this have been caused by either MS' "for real this is the last exception" recent XP update automatically being applied (she did have automatic updates set), or possibly the zero-day vulnerability it was meant to patch being taken advantage of (despite her normal usage pattern)?  Or was it likely a hardware fluke?

Comment: Are you actually trying to fix this, or do you just want to guess at and discuss possible causes?  What does the Event Log say about the reboots?  What have you tried already to fix it?

Comment: Man, you are jumping all over the place. Try doing some research. Did anything you read about the IE Zero-Day exploit mention these symptoms? No they did not. So that is a very unlikely cause. What is more probable is that a BSOD is occurring and the computer is set to automatically restart upon system failure. The key is to disable that option so that you can see the BSOD and troubleshoot it. Try starting in `Safe Mode with Command Prompt` and typing this: `wmic recoveros set AutoReboot = False`. Then reboot and see what happens.

Comment: @techie007, I'm not sure yet.  I'll probably try to recover her files before anything else, but I am wondering about possible causes so that when I make the trip I can be prepared with appropriate materials.  How can I get to the Event Log without being able to boot in any manner?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I couldn't find anything on the exploit mentioning this, but exploits can cause any change--a botched hack can render a system unbootable like this.  Anyway, your points highlighted an inconsistency in her story.  She said she tried every option and got the same result, but I guess that can't include the command prompt option, otherwise it wouldn't have shown any logos.  I'll go from there...sorry, this should probably be closed.

Comment: Understood. If she has the automatically restart option set that's why nothing is working for her. The system is restarting upon the BSOD, so no F8 options allow her to get past it. The trick is to turn off the automatically restart option so that you see the BSOD and can troubleshoot it, which hopefully you can do from `Safe Mode with Command Prompt`. If you can't then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @joeqwerty, It turned out I couldn't even boot `Safe Mode with Command Prompt` without a BSOD/auto-restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about the reason, but it seems to me that the only best and fastest option is to do a repair install of xp; this will only "reset" the whole xp, but you **wont** loose any of your data. But some programs will need reinstall, and it will be pain in the ass to do it, as well as to make all those settings in windows and programs to make them like before (passwords, settings..). I have done it many times so there is nothing to worry about.

Be aware that there are two "repair" methods; the one that uses the recovery console (NOT THIS ONE), 
and the other method that you choose the existing xp setup in the disk(s)/partitions and then you either choose "**To repair the selected windows xp installation, press R**" OR "To continue installing a fresh copy of windows xp without repairing, press ESC.". Obvisously you choose the first option.

Dont forget to ALWAYS disable updates, there are meaningless, and BTW XP rocks, no matter what the trolls say to you (Yeah, the windows itself and the hackers waited for this last day to frack with xp machines... Yeap.. Right..)

Comment: "ALWAYS disable updates, there are meaningless" They aren't, especially the security-related ones.

Comment: Actually, you need only hotfixes for specific things. Security ones ok, but if you have good antivirus/firewall, all ok.

Comment: I didn't have access to install media, but I would have liked to have tried this.

Answer (score -1):

Press `F8` after the bios though *before* the Windows boot logo; if you do this correctly you'll see a boot menu, if not then keep pressing F8 after the computer boots frequently/quickly.

Enter safe mode.

Once in safe mode go to `START`, `Run`, type `msconfig` and press enter. Under the `Services` tab check the box that says `Hide all Microsoft Services`. Then disable all your remaining services. Go to the Startup tab and disable all the programs there. You may or may not opt to keep your anti-virus running, if the problem persists and you leave it enabled then disable it to see if *that* is the cause of the problem.

Restart...again if the problem persists disable the antivirus and any other security software.

If that still doesn't work then you'll want to upgrade to Windows 7. I've been putting a tutorial together to help people make 7 like XP so if that is an issue for you contact me through my site in my profile.

If you run in to something else let me know and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: As I mentioned, she did try safe mode, at least, and it rebooted before she was able to use anything.  (At least, I have to assume she tried more than 'normal' if she 'tried all the options' in the menu.  She doesn't need help getting to the F8 menu, it comes up by itself every time.)  This doesn't help as much as joeqwerty's comment on the question...